# How do I load my java event using from an external link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a visiual menu system that when clicked fills the designated area with an image and approriate text. Below I have included an example of the containers and script used on the page.

There are around 20 of them in all and each has its own individual # tag. If I try to reference the page via a link like the one below. It doesn't change the content of the page to match the unique # tag. I think this is due to the script being a click event only. Can someone give me an idea of how fix this so I can use this link externally on other html pages within the site and have the appropriate # information show up.

http://jets.chiefaircraft.com/skymaster/available-models.html#af816sw

The menu html:

```
<div class="box">
<a href="#bh248" class="scheme-links" data-scheme="bh248">
  <div class="boxinner">
    <img src="http://cdn1.chiefaircraft.com/skymaster/images/gallery/bae-t1/BH248.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="titlebox">BAE Hawk T-1 - In Stock<br />RAF 2004 Scheme
    </div>
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
     $('.scheme-links').click(function(event){
     var scheme = $(this).attr('data-scheme');
     $('.gallery').hide(event);
     $('#gallery_' + scheme).show(event);
   });
});
```

The event references this information to fill the selected areas:

```
<div id="gallery_bh248" class="gallery">
<div class="gallery-image"><img src="http://cdn1.chiefaircraft.com/skymaster/images/gallery/bae-t1/BH248.jpg" alt=""/></div>
<div class="gallery-info">
<div class="gallery-text">
<h2><u>Skymaster PRO ARF Plus</u><br />
BAE Hawk T-1:</h2>
<h3>RAF 2004 Scheme (BH248)<br />
In Stock: Only $5,199.50 + Freight</h3>
</div>
<div class="gallery-upgrade">
<p><b>Includes the Following Upgrades:</b></p>
<ul><li>Jet Airframe: BH248 RAF 2004 Scheme</li>
<li>Scale Landing Gear: AP921</li>
<li>Speed Brake Assembly Factory Installed</li>
<li>Landing Gear &amp; Doors Factory Installed</li>
<li>Cylinder Set for Gear Doors: AP925</li>
<li>Cockpit Details w/o Pilot: AP927</li>
<li>Exhaust Pipe (P120-P160): AP923</li>
<li>Complete Air Kit: AP921K</li>
<li>Kevlar Fuel Tank: AP922</li>
<li>Hardware Kit: AP924</li>
<li>Wing Bag</li></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Expected behavior is not clear at all. Also no html given for us to know where the url's and hash values need to come from. What does `as if user clicked button` mean? javascript redirect?

Comment: Made some edits. Hope this is a little more clear to the issue. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Is  what you want?
Once the website loads, you can recognize what hash came with it, and make a proper function to load it.

Please elaborate your code further so if this isn't the correct answer, I can be of help/edit.

```
$(function()
{
    // Moving page to hash on open
    var hash = null;
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
            hash = window.location.hash;
            window.location.hash = '';
            window.location = hash;
    }
});
```

Comment: post code in answer not in pastebin....external links rot making answer useless at that time. Not to mention it takes a lot more effort to review answers